# Need help in query finding first and last item in item groups

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need help in getting this type of output:

```
Create table T1
(Id int identity primary key,
VoucherNo varchar(10),
TransNo varchar(10)
)

Insert into T1 values ('V100','Trns1'),('V101','Trns1'),('V102','Trns1'),('V103','Trns1'),('V104','Trns1'),('V106','Trns1')
```

Resultant output:

```
TransNo FirsvoucherNo  LastVoucherNo Quantity
trans1    V100     V104  5
trans1   V106      V106   1
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve sir?

Comment: All of your data is Trns1 but the output shown trans2??

Answer (score 1):

If voucher numbers are formatted with a fixed number of digits, this can be solved with a simple `GROUP BY` query:

```
SELECT
    TransNo,
    MIN(VoucherNo) as FirsvoucherNo,
    MAX(VoucherNo) as LastVoucherNo,
    COUNT(*) as Quantity
FROM T1
GROUP BY TransNo
```

[Here is a demo on sqlfiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8e5da/1)

Comment: this will not work.. i tried it already

Comment: @KapilSingh Did you follow a link to a demo at the bottom of the answer?